# JavaScript: Can I add decimals?

Tags: javascript, loops

```
for( count = 0.01; count <= 0.20; count + 0.01 )
```

Is this valid? Because it seems as soon as I changed it to this from `count++`, my firefox crashed.

Comment: Kepp in mind that JavaScript and decimals don´t always play nice together. If you doing critical calculations you better convert the decimals to whole numbers and at the end convert it back to decimals.

Comment: Not just Javascript. In all widely-used languages floatings points seldom play nice as a for-loop index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for( count = 0.01; count <= 0.20; count += 0.01 )
```

You were missing an `=` operator in the last section of the for loop. Otherwise it would be an ***infinite loop***.

Answer (score 2):

If you use this code, you'll get values like

- 0.060000000000000005
- 0.11999999999999998

If you really want a predictable count, keep the loop integer, and rescale down to the fractional number you need:

```
for( count = 1; count <= 20; count++ ) console.log(count/100)
```

This produces values like 0.06 and 0.12, like you would expect.